# Moment of a triangular load (Integration method)

Tags: integration

On my course of structural engineering we often have to calculate the moment of a load.
I had always solved it geometrically (that is, area of triangle as equivalent force and depending if the triangle was descending or increasing it is multiplied for L/3 or 2L/3).

Recently, I tried the integration approach and i got stuck in the calculus of the intregral for the descending triangle:
[image]
And its function is:

$$q=\frac{q_a}{(\alpha-\beta)}(x-\beta)$$

Also important to define $L=\beta-\alpha$.

Therefore, the integral in which I am stuck is:

$$\int_{\alpha}^\beta x\bigl(\frac{q_a}{(\alpha-\beta)}(x-\beta)\bigr) dx$$

I know that it's solution is $\frac{q_a L}{2}(\alpha+\frac{L}{3})$ but i don't know how to simplify up to that solution.

If someone can help it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $\alpha,L$ rather than $\alpha,\beta$ in the final answer, it is better to use the substitution $x=\alpha+uL$, $\beta=\alpha+L$ in the integral first, rather than substituting after the integration.

So we have $\mathrm{d}x=L\,\mathrm{d}u$ and
\begin{align*}
\int_\alpha^\beta x\frac{q_a}{\alpha-\beta}(x-\beta)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1 (\alpha+uL)q_a(1-u)L\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=q_aL\int_0^1 (\alpha(1-u)+(u-u^2)L)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=q_aL\left[\alpha(u-\frac12u^2)+(\frac12u^2-\frac13u^3)L\right]_0^1\\
&=q_aL\left(\frac12\alpha+\frac16L\right)\\
&=\frac{q_aL}{2}\left(\alpha+\frac13L\right).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the origin $O$ at the $x$ axis origin we have

$$
\frac{0-q_a}{\beta-\alpha} = \frac{q(x)-q_a}{x-\alpha}\Rightarrow q(x) = q_a-\frac{q_a}{\beta-\alpha}(x-\alpha)
$$

now

$$
M_O = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}q(x) x dx = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\left(q_a-\frac{q_a}{\beta-\alpha}(x-\alpha)\right) x dx
$$

then

$$
M_O = \frac{\beta ^2 q_a}{2}-\frac{\alpha ^2 q_a}{2}-\frac{\beta ^3 q_a}{3 (\beta -\alpha
   )}+\frac{\alpha  \beta ^2 q_a}{2 (\beta -\alpha )}-\frac{\alpha ^3 q_a}{6 (\beta -\alpha )} = \frac{1}{6} q_a (\beta -\alpha) (2 \alpha +\beta )
$$

but $L = \beta-\alpha$ so

$$
M_O = \frac {q_a}{2}L\left(\frac L3+\alpha\right)
$$